# GCP cloud functions(Gen1) not inserting json data into BigQuery table

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am using GCP cloud function (Gen1) with HTTP trigger which fetches the FOREX currency exchange price through a web api.

I use requests library to fetch the data and read it as json and insert the json data into BigQuery table.

Sample json data:

```
  {
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1679000163,
    "base": "GBP",
    "date": "2023-03-16",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 4.448146
    }
}
```

I define the BigQuery schema and use insert_rows() method to insert json data in BQ table.

I tried couple of methods.
Method: 1

Insert the json data in a list as dict and getting error below - ValueError: The number of row fields (1) does not match schema length (4).

Method: 2

Tried inserting as json but NO ERROR but the BQ table is empty.

Schema below,

```
 schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("timestamp", "DATE", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("base_currency", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("exchange_date", "DATE", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("exchange_rates", "RECORD", mode="REPEATED",
                  fields=[
                     bigquery.SchemaField("exchange_currency", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
                  ],
    ),
]
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you

## Method: 1

```
rows_to_insert = [
    (
      data['timestamp'],
      data["base"],
      data["date"],
      dict(exchange_currency = data['rates']['EUR']),
    )
  ]

table_id = 'project.dataset.table'
  client = bigquery.Client()
  errors = client.insert_rows(table_id, [rows_to_insert], selected_fields=schema)
```

## Method: 1 - error

ValueError: The number of row fields (1) does not match schema length (4).

## Method: 2

```
  rows_to_insert = {'timestamp': data['timestamp'], 
            'base_currency': data["base"],
            'exchange_date':data["date"],
            'exchange_currency':[data['rates']['EUR']],
            }

table_id = 'project.dataset.table'
  client = bigquery.Client()
  errors = client.insert_rows(table_id, [rows_to_insert], selected_fields=schema)
```

## Method: 2 - NO error

No error but data not loading into BigQuery table (empty table)

## Complete script below

```
from os import getenv
import requests 
from google.cloud import bigquery

def hello_world(request):
  API_KEY = getenv("API_KEY")
  BASE_CURRENCY = getenv("BASE_CURRENCY")   
  SYB1 = getenv("SYB1")  #EUR

  url = f"https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?symbols={SYB1}&base={BASE_CURRENCY}"
  payload = {}
  headers= {
  "apikey": API_KEY
}
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
  status_code = response.status_code
  data = response.json()

  schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("timestamp", "DATE", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("base_currency", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("exchange_date", "DATE", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("exchange_rates", "RECORD", mode="REPEATED",
                  fields=[
                     bigquery.SchemaField("exchange_currency", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
                  ],
    ),
]
  # method: 1
  rows_to_insert = [
    (
      data['timestamp'],
      data["base"],
      data["date"],
      dict(exchange_currency = data['rates']['EUR']),
    )
  ]
  
  # method: 2
  rows_to_insert = {'timestamp': data['timestamp'], 
            'base_currency': data["base"],
            'exchange_date':data["date"],
            'exchange_currency':[data['rates']['EUR']],
            }

  table_id = 'zinc-forge-380121.etlpipeline.forex_rates'
  client = bigquery.Client()
  errors = client.insert_rows(table_id, [rows_to_insert], selected_fields=schema)

  return f'status code {status_code}'
```

Comment: Empty table? How did you check? Did you use preview or a query?

Comment: @Guillaume, thanks for your reply. I did both, previewed as well as queried it. Thanks

Comment: And, still empty table? In fact, when you stream write the data, they are not immediately available for the preview because they are cached in a temp partition. However, a query will read that temp partition and you should see your data. There is a temporarily desynchronization between query and preview with stream write.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, yes I agree that. But unfortunately, right now even this minute the table is empty!!

Comment: peeps any lead on this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried gen2 or do you prefer to only use your current gen?

Comment: Hi Poala Astrid, not yet mate I prefer to stick with gen1 for time being.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your suggestions. Fixed the issue, couple of things here, 1.) timestamp column schema was date then changed schema to timestamp itself. 2.) In the dictionary, I have to include the exchange_rates column and then exchange_currency in the nested field. Thanks fot